# Spring Service with @DependsOn requiring a configuration from another artifact

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in our project we have a **commons module** that among other things contains a configuration class that executes some custom code for our database.

```
@Configuration
public class DbMigration {

   [...]

   @PostConstruct
   public void doStuff() { // Has to run first
      [...]
   }
}
```

In the **main project** we have a service class that has a @PostConstruct block that requires the DbMigration to have run already.

```
@Service
@DependsOn("dbMigration")
public class ElasticSearchMigrationService {
   [...]

   @PostConstruct
   public void doStuff() { // Has to run second
      [...]
   }
}
```

The above solution used to work when the `DbMigration` class was still in the same module as the `ElasticSearchMigrationService`, but ever since we moved the Migration into our commons module Spring fails to start with an exception.

```
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dbMigration' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:872)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        ... 57 more
```

One solution that I found but don't really like would be to create a @Bean of type `DbMigration` inside the `DbMigration` class. I also cannot move the ElasticSearchMigrationService  into the commons module as it contains very specific code required only for this application.

Are there any other solutions, or am I overlookin something?

Comment: `@Configuration` does not create beans change to `@Service`

Comment: That much I am aware off, but for some reason it used to work when they were in the same module. Now that they are in different modules/artifacts it doesn't anymore..

Comment: If the only thing you did was move them around it shouldn't make any difference... What I suspect that actually happend is that you moved it to a different module **and** also changed the package name, leading to this not being discovered by your Spring Boot regular scan, and thus no bean being created. Add an `@Import(DbMigration.class)` on your `@SpringBooApplication` or add the package to scan with `@ComponentScan` so it gets detected again. Also `@Configuration` **does** create a bean as you can just inject it as a regular `@Component`, in fact `@Configuration` **is an `@Component`**...

Comment: The DbMigration class is being imported via AutoConfiguration, which does seem to work cause as long as i add
```
    @Bean
    public DbMigration dbMigration(...) {
        return new DbMigration(...);
    }
```
to the `DbMigration` class it does work...

Comment: It isn't imported else you wouldn't get a missing bean.. Unless the name changed in that autoconfiguration.